# Ancient VGA card causes freeze

Tags: nvidia, vga

I am a recovering Window user evaluating ***Linux Mint*** (19.3 Cinnamon 4.4.8) as a replacement OS for my venerable HP 505B Desktop. But apparently the installed Nvidia VGA card (GeForce 6150SE nForce 430) occasionally causes a freeze up and reboot.

It appears that the ***Nouveau*** driver (as provided by the kernel) is installed (instead of the Nvidia driver I think). As a Linux newbie I can only run `inxi -G` successfully but not much else. Is there any hope of fixing this situation?

Comment: Exactly how have you concluded that the Nouveau driver seems to be the reason? Does your system manage to save any logs from the crashes? Run `journalctl --list-boots`: if it shows just one line, the journals of previous boots are not being saved - in that case, try `sudo mkdir /var/log/journal` and after a reboot, the system should start accumulating persistent logs. Then after a freeze+reboot, you should be able to run `journalctl -b -1  -e` to view the last messages from the previous boot, from the time just before the freeze.

Comment: It seems to be that GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 is not a separate card, but an integrated  GPU in the nForce 430 system chipset. So you cannot easily remove it. You might be able to add another display card and change the BIOS settings to disable the integrated GPU if you think it has a hardware fault, but since it is part of the system chipset, a fault in it might affect other chipset functions too.

Comment: Thanx for the explanation abt Nvidia VGA function.  An integrated GPU really complicates the Linux situation but makes Windows look good since Windows 10 ran successfully before replacing with Linux.